# absolute file reference path not recognizing "\b" in subfolder "\bobby" of my file reference string as text

Tags: python, string, directory, byte, decode

apologies if this has been asked before. I am currently learning to read/write to files using absolute referencing in Python. I am unfortunate enough to be named Bobby - meaning that my absolute reference for some files will be "C:\Users\bobby...", however it seems like the "\b" is changing the way that this is being read by Python. Again, I'm still learning, so I'm not sure how I would be able to reformat the string so that it accepts "\b" as an ACTUAL string. Would anyone be able to help me?

example inside of a class definition:

```
def get_high_score(self):
    with open("C:\Users\bobby\Desktop\data.txt") as file:
        contents = (file.read())
        self.high_score = int(contents)
```

the contents of this file merely contain a single integer on the first line. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Python (be default) uses `\` to escape a character. This is used for writing newlines `\n` and more.
To make your string accept `\` as it is, write it with a `r` preceding the string:

```py
def get_high_score(self):
    with open(r"C:\Users\bobby\Desktop\data.txt") as file:  # Note the "r" before the string!
        contents = (file.read())
        self.high_score = int(contents)
```

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote you but I need at least 15 contribution lol.

Comment: No problem! You should still have the option to mark it as accepted if I recall correctly.